# Calling a function from an object property without using brackets

Tags: javascript

Although my title seems kinda wonky, I tried to describe exactly what I am trying to do. Say I have an object:

```
function testObj(data) {
    this.id = data.id
    this.getObjFromId = function() {
        //Return some value from somewhere using the this.id
    }
    this.obj = this.getObjFromId();
}
```

The reason for doing this is so I can update the this.id property and this.obj will always return some other object using the updated id. Right now what this does is it initially calls the getObjFromId function using the original id and stores the returned value in this.obj. If I do something like this:

```
var testObj = new TestObj({id: 1});
alert(testObj.obj); //Returns Foo1
testObj.id = 5; //Update the object with a new id
alert(testObj.obj); //Returns Foo1, but should return Foo5
```

This would be simple if I could just call the this.obj function as a function like this.obj(), but for a variety of reasons this is not possible (templating etc etc.) so I need to be able to get a dynamic value from the this.obj "function" by simple using this.obj.

I hope this makes sense. As i'm writing I understand its confusing, so maybe there is a better approach to doing this. None the less, the functionality I am proposing needs to work the same where I can call a dynamic value from an object property. My questions title might be better suited as something more descriptive of my problem if someone cares to update, but I couldn't think of a better way to describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) for your `obj` property:

```
function TestObj(data) {
    this.id = data.id
    Object.defineProperty(this, "obj", {
        get: function() {
            //Return some value from somewhere using the this.id
        }
    });
}
```

as well, you could use a setter function for the `id` property which updates the `obj` property only when you set the id. This could be useful for caching.

```
function TestObj(data) {
    var id = data.id, obj;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {
        get: function() { return id; },
        set: function(newval) {
            id = newval;
            obj = this.getObjFromId();
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "obj", {
        get: function() { return obj; }
    });
}
TestObj.prototype.getObjFromId = function() {
    //Return some value from somewhere using the this.id
};
```

Comment: IE 9+, FF 4+, Chrome 5+, Safari 5.1+, Opera 11.6+

Comment: The [`get` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) and the [`__defineGetter__` deprecated method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) were supported in legacy versions - of course you can't expect it to work in IE :-/

Comment: How would I incorporate the _defineGetter_ to support earlier versions as well? And are you saying that even by using the _defineGetter_, it won't work in previous IE versions?

Comment: The [es5 shim library](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) provides some useful stuff for older browsers, but is limited of course. For the IE8 issue see https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/issues/5

Comment: How can I make obj actually available for use in the DOM? I can reference testObj.obj. For instance, in firebug if I inspect the object, obj is no available in the list.

Comment: You cannot support getters for older versions of IE, as it didn't exist in earlier versions of JavaScript. The best option you have in that case is to use `testObj.setId(5);` and have `this.setId = function(id) { /* change this.obj in setId method */ };`

Comment: @ryandlf: I guess you should set `enumerable:true` in the params for `defineProperty` - it's a Firebug bug. You can use it even if it is not listed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call `getObjFromId` directly like

```
var testObj = new TestObj({id: 1});
alert(testObj.getObjFromId());
```

Additionally, your code is not optimal since it will create an instance of `getObjFromId` for every `TestObj` instance you create. You should declare `getObjFromId` as a value of TestObj's prototype:

```
function TestObj(data) {...}
TestObj.prototype.getObjFromId = function(){...}
```

---

**EDIT**

If calling `getObjFromId` directly is not an option, then I would create another function to update object's state.
Instead of calling

```
testObj.id = 'newId';
```

you would call

```
testObj.update('newId');//internally, call getObjFromId and/or update id field
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tip. I agree, but as I mentioned in the question I cannot call the getObjFromId as a function like this. This is due to the way my templating is set up and a few other reasons.